# Creation of Separate Backup List<String>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I need to create a backup copy of a `List<String>`

```
OrgList=new List<string>();
//populating OrgList
ListBackup = new List<string>(OrgList);
```

Does `ListBackup` stay as a separate entity or are the changes in `OrgList` auto reflected in ListBackup

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListBackup = new List<string>(OrgList);
```

calls [`List<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor, so
you get a brand-new list out of it.

Since `string` is *immutable*, changes to `OrgList` cannot be made visible through `ListBackup`. However, this is not a deep copy; if you do the same thing to a collection of mutable objects, modifications of objects in `OrgList` would be visible in `ListBackup` as well.

You can make a read-only view of the list by calling [`AsReadOnly()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
ListView = OrgList.AsReadOnly();
```

Now any change to `OrgList` is also reflected in `ListView`.

Comment: @techno Yes, with strings and other immutable classes the two behave as completely independent.